# Масштабирование, размеры иконок в одном приложении отличаются друг от друга SVG

Tags: css, svg

Столкнулся с неожиданной странностью - делал вот такой блок:
[image: Блок с svg картинками]
Все svg картинки в выносках отображались корректно, кроме трех - верхней слева и двух нижних справа. Эти картинки отображались не полностью, как будто часть скрыта.
Некорректное отображение было только на больших экранах, то есть если посредством прокрутки масштабировать экран до версии мобилки, то отображение становилось корректным.
Попытки изменить стилизацию родительских элементов ни к чему не привели.
Но сама странность не в этом, проблема решается, если вставить в шапку сайта верхнюю левую картинку (даже с display:none) (изначально попробовал вставить в шапку, так как думал что дело в абсолютном позиционировании родителя), тогда все три картинки отображаются полностью. В чем может быть дело?

Пример первой SVG:

```html
 <svg width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 30 30" fill="none" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g clip-path="url(#clip0)">
        <path d="M26.8762 11.8749C25.3661 11.8749 24.1048 12.95 23.8148 14.375H22.2635L19.7222 9.29361C18.9771 7.80106 17.4758 6.87478 15.8083 6.87478H15.0008V4.99973C15.0008 4.65472 14.7207 4.37469 14.3757 4.37469H9.37559C9.03057 4.37469 8.75055 4.65472 8.75055 4.99973V9.99986C8.75055 10.3449 9.03057 10.6249 9.37559 10.6249H14.3757C14.7207 10.6249 15.0008 10.3449 15.0008 9.99986V8.1248H15.8083C17.0008 8.1248 18.0721 8.78606 18.6033 9.85238L20.8647 14.375H2.13411L4.81667 11.6925C5.06043 11.4487 5.06043 11.0524 4.81667 10.8087C4.57292 10.5649 4.17663 10.5649 3.93288 10.8087L0.184049 14.5575C0.126566 14.615 0.0802759 14.685 0.047814 14.7612C-0.015938 14.9137 -0.015938 15.0863 0.047814 15.2387C0.0790454 15.3162 0.125336 15.385 0.184049 15.4425L3.93294 19.1913C4.05546 19.3139 4.21542 19.3751 4.37545 19.3751C4.53547 19.3751 4.69544 19.3139 4.81796 19.1926C5.06172 18.9488 5.06172 18.5525 4.81796 18.3088L2.13411 15.6249H22.1147L19.8534 20.1476C19.3209 21.2138 18.2509 21.8751 17.0583 21.8751H16.1883C15.8983 20.4501 14.6358 19.375 13.127 19.375C11.4019 19.375 10.0006 20.7764 10.0006 22.5001C10.0006 24.2239 11.4019 25.6252 13.1257 25.6252C14.6358 25.6252 15.897 24.5501 16.187 23.1251H17.0571C18.7259 23.1251 20.2259 22.1988 20.9709 20.7063L23.5123 15.6249H23.8135C24.1035 17.0499 25.3661 18.125 26.8749 18.125C28.5987 18.125 29.9999 16.7236 29.9999 14.9999C30 13.2762 28.6 11.8749 26.8762 11.8749Z" fill="#4F4F4F"/>
        </g>
        <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip0">
        <rect width="30" height="30" fill="white"/>
        </clipPath>
        </defs>
    </svg>
```

Привожу пример кода:

1) Блок который отображен на картинке:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './functions-block.css';
import Function from './Function/Function';

export default class FunctionsBlock extends Component{
    render(){

        const constructorImg = <svg className="function__function-img" width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 30 30" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <g clipPath="url(#clip0)">
                <path d="M26.8762 11.8749C25.3661 11.8749 24.1048 12.95 23.8148 14.375H22.2635L19.7222 9.29361C18.9771 7.80106 17.4758 6.87478 15.8083 6.87478H15.0008V4.99973C15.0008 4.65472 14.7207 4.37469 14.3757 4.37469H9.37559C9.03057 4.37469 8.75055 4.65472 8.75055 4.99973V9.99986C8.75055 10.3449 9.03057 10.6249 9.37559 10.6249H14.3757C14.7207 10.6249 15.0008 10.3449 15.0008 9.99986V8.1248H15.8083C17.0008 8.1248 18.0721 8.78606 18.6033 9.85238L20.8647 14.375H2.13411L4.81667 11.6925C5.06043 11.4487 5.06043 11.0524 4.81667 10.8087C4.57292 10.5649 4.17663 10.5649 3.93288 10.8087L0.184049 14.5575C0.126566 14.615 0.0802759 14.685 0.047814 14.7612C-0.015938 14.9137 -0.015938 15.0863 0.047814 15.2387C0.0790454 15.3162 0.125336 15.385 0.184049 15.4425L3.93294 19.1913C4.05546 19.3139 4.21542 19.3751 4.37545 19.3751C4.53547 19.3751 4.69544 19.3139 4.81796 19.1926C5.06172 18.9488 5.06172 18.5525 4.81796 18.3088L2.13411 15.6249H22.1147L19.8534 20.1476C19.3209 21.2138 18.2509 21.8751 17.0583 21.8751H16.1883C15.8983 20.4501 14.6358 19.375 13.127 19.375C11.4019 19.375 10.0006 20.7764 10.0006 22.5001C10.0006 24.2239 11.4019 25.6252 13.1257 25.6252C14.6358 25.6252 15.897 24.5501 16.187 23.1251H17.0571C18.7259 23.1251 20.2259 22.1988 20.9709 20.7063L23.5123 15.6249H23.8135C24.1035 17.0499 25.3661 18.125 26.8749 18.125C28.5987 18.125 29.9999 16.7236 29.9999 14.9999C30 13.2762 28.6 11.8749 26.8762 11.8749Z" fill="#4F4F4F"/>
            </g>
            <defs>
                <clipPath id="clip0">
                    <rect width="30" height="30" fill="white"/>
                </clipPath>
            </defs>
        </svg>;

        const userMonitoringImg = <svg className="function__function-img" width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 30 30" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M15 0C6.72915 0 0 6.72915 0 15C0 23.2708 6.72915 29.9999 15 29.9999C23.2708 29.9999 29.9999 23.2708 29.9999 15C29.9999 6.72915 23.2709 0 15 0ZM15 3.91304C17.5174 3.91304 19.5652 5.96085 19.5652 8.47828C19.5652 10.9957 17.5174 13.0435 15 13.0435C12.4825 13.0435 10.4347 10.9957 10.4347 8.47828C10.4347 5.96085 12.4826 3.91304 15 3.91304ZM22.8261 23.4782H7.17389C6.81389 23.4782 6.52169 23.1861 6.52169 22.8261C6.52169 18.1513 10.3252 14.3478 15 14.3478C19.6748 14.3478 23.4782 18.1513 23.4782 22.8261C23.4782 23.1861 23.1861 23.4782 22.8261 23.4782Z" fill="#4F4F4F"/>
        </svg>;

        const starImg = <svg className="function__function-img" width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 30 30" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M29.9696 11.5149C29.8822 11.2449 29.6318 11.061 29.3474 11.061H18.7394L15.6221 1.08424C15.4512 0.541628 14.5473 0.541628 14.3765 1.08424L11.2592 11.061H0.65253C0.368169 11.061 0.117741 11.2449 0.0303719 11.5149C-0.054429 11.7849 0.0421107 12.0796 0.272974 12.2453L8.99621 18.4747L5.25935 28.441C5.1589 28.7097 5.24498 29.0123 5.47193 29.1871C5.70017 29.3632 6.01192 29.3658 6.24933 29.2014L15 22.9498L23.7506 29.2014C23.8653 29.2823 23.9971 29.3227 24.1301 29.3227C24.2697 29.3227 24.4106 29.2784 24.528 29.1871C24.7549 29.0123 24.841 28.7097 24.7406 28.441L21.0037 18.4747L29.7269 12.2453C29.9579 12.0796 30.0544 11.7849 29.9696 11.5149Z" fill="#4F4F4F"/>
        </svg>;

        const autoPostingImg = <svg className="function__function-img" width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 30 30" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M14.9998 15.6536C15.3608 15.6536 15.6534 15.361 15.6534 15C15.6534 14.639 15.3608 14.3464 14.9998 14.3464C14.6388 14.3464 14.3462 14.639 14.3462 15C14.3462 15.361 14.6388 15.6536 14.9998 15.6536Z" fill="#4F4F4F"/>
            <path d="M28.0118 15C28.0118 14.6392 28.3046 14.3464 28.6654 14.3464H30C29.664 6.56734 23.4314 0.33462 15.6536 0V1.33333C15.6536 1.69412 15.3608 1.98695 15 1.98695C14.6392 1.98695 14.3464 1.69412 14.3464 1.33333V0C6.56734 0.33462 0.33462 6.56734 0 14.3464H1.33462C1.6954 14.3464 1.98824 14.6392 1.98824 15C1.98824 15.3608 1.6954 15.6536 1.33462 15.6536H0C0.33462 23.4314 6.56734 29.664 14.3464 30V28.6667C14.3464 28.3059 14.6392 28.0131 15 28.0131C15.3608 28.0131 15.6536 28.3059 15.6536 28.6667V30C23.4314 29.6654 29.664 23.4327 30 15.6536H28.6654C28.3046 15.6536 28.0118 15.3608 28.0118 15ZM20.6902 20.6902C20.5621 20.8183 20.3948 20.8811 20.2275 20.8811C20.0601 20.8811 19.8928 20.817 19.7647 20.6902L15.8431 16.7686C15.8419 16.7673 15.8405 16.7647 15.8392 16.7634C15.583 16.8863 15.3007 16.9608 14.9974 16.9608C13.9163 16.9608 13.0366 16.0811 13.0366 15C13.0366 14.149 13.5843 13.4301 14.3438 13.1595V5.84969C14.3438 5.48891 14.6366 5.19608 14.9974 5.19608C15.3581 5.19608 15.651 5.48891 15.651 5.84969V13.1595C16.4105 13.4301 16.9581 14.149 16.9581 15C16.9581 15.302 16.8836 15.5856 16.7608 15.8419C16.7621 15.8431 16.7647 15.8445 16.766 15.8458L20.6876 19.7673C20.9464 20.0222 20.9464 20.4353 20.6902 20.6902Z" fill="#4F4F4F"/>
        </svg>;

        const refreshImg = <svg className="function__function-img" width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 30 30" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M15.6027 3.01332C15.5701 2.93243 15.5218 2.86071 15.4605 2.80073L12.8531 0.190759C12.5988 -0.0635863 12.1853 -0.0635863 11.9309 0.190759C11.6766 0.445104 11.6766 0.858598 11.9309 1.11294L13.5235 2.70553C7.38538 3.43983 2.60889 8.66895 2.60889 15.0002C2.60889 20.8358 6.5845 25.8027 12.2766 27.0822C12.3249 27.0927 12.3718 27.0979 12.4188 27.0979C12.7175 27.0979 12.9874 26.8918 13.0553 26.5879C13.1349 26.2358 12.9132 25.8875 12.5623 25.808C7.47018 24.6654 3.91326 20.2202 3.91326 15.0002C3.91326 9.47509 7.9815 4.89296 13.2784 4.06078L11.9297 5.40813C11.6753 5.66248 11.6753 6.07597 11.9297 6.33032C12.0575 6.45816 12.2244 6.52206 12.3914 6.52206C12.5584 6.52206 12.7253 6.45816 12.8531 6.3316L15.4605 3.72426C15.5204 3.66428 15.5687 3.59122 15.6026 3.51167C15.6692 3.35246 15.6692 3.17247 15.6027 3.01332Z" fill="#4F4F4F"/>
            <path d="M27.3913 15.0002C27.3913 9.16463 23.4157 4.19768 17.7236 2.91813C17.3675 2.8425 17.0232 3.06029 16.9436 3.41246C16.8641 3.76463 17.0858 4.11288 17.4379 4.19243C22.53 5.33502 26.087 9.78019 26.087 15.0001C26.087 20.5253 22.0187 25.1074 16.7219 25.9396L18.0692 24.5922C18.3236 24.3379 18.3236 23.9244 18.0692 23.6701C17.8149 23.4157 17.4014 23.4157 17.147 23.6701L14.5397 26.2774C14.4797 26.3374 14.4314 26.4104 14.3975 26.49C14.331 26.6491 14.331 26.8291 14.3975 26.9882C14.4301 27.0691 14.4784 27.1408 14.5397 27.2008L17.147 29.8082C17.2749 29.936 17.4418 29.9999 17.6088 29.9999C17.7758 29.9999 17.9427 29.936 18.0705 29.8094C18.3249 29.5551 18.3249 29.1416 18.0705 28.8873L16.4779 27.2947C22.6149 26.5605 27.3913 21.3314 27.3913 15.0002Z" fill="#4F4F4F"/>
        </svg>;

        const communituFillingImg = <svg className="function__function-img" width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 30 30" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M29.375 5.625H9.37502C9.03002 5.625 8.75 5.90502 8.75 6.25002C8.75 6.59502 9.03002 6.87504 9.37502 6.87504H29.375C29.72 6.87504 30 6.59502 30 6.25002C30 5.90502 29.72 5.625 29.375 5.625Z" fill="#4F4F4F"/>
            <path d="M29.375 14.375H9.37502C9.03002 14.375 8.75 14.655 8.75 15C8.75 15.345 9.03002 15.625 9.37502 15.625H29.375C29.72 15.625 30 15.345 30 15C30 14.655 29.72 14.375 29.375 14.375Z" fill="#4F4F4F"/>
            <path d="M29.375 23.125H9.37502C9.03002 23.125 8.75 23.405 8.75 23.75C8.75 24.095 9.03002 24.3751 9.37502 24.3751H29.375C29.72 24.3751 30 24.095 30 23.75C30 23.405 29.72 23.125 29.375 23.125Z" fill="#4F4F4F"/>
            <path d="M3.12498 26.875C4.85086 26.875 6.24996 25.4759 6.24996 23.75C6.24996 22.0241 4.85086 20.625 3.12498 20.625C1.3991 20.625 0 22.0241 0 23.75C0 25.4759 1.3991 26.875 3.12498 26.875Z" fill="#4F4F4F"/>
            <path d="M3.12498 18.125C4.85086 18.125 6.24996 16.7259 6.24996 15C6.24996 13.2741 4.85086 11.875 3.12498 11.875C1.3991 11.875 0 13.2741 0 15C0 16.7259 1.3991 18.125 3.12498 18.125Z" fill="#4F4F4F"/>
            <path d="M3.12498 9.37501C4.85086 9.37501 6.24996 7.97591 6.24996 6.25003C6.24996 4.52415 4.85086 3.12505 3.12498 3.12505C1.3991 3.12505 0 4.52415 0 6.25003C0 7.97591 1.3991 9.37501 3.12498 9.37501Z" fill="#4F4F4F"/>
        </svg>;

        const botsCleaningImg = <svg className="function__function-img" width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 30 30" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M21.9505 3.2634C19.2416 3.2634 16.708 2.05976 14.9998 0C13.2931 2.0584 10.7594 3.2634 8.05055 3.2634C6.31321 3.2634 4.63014 2.76585 3.18604 1.84295V15.5149C3.18604 22.6337 13.0373 28.8353 14.9998 30C16.9608 28.8353 26.8135 22.6268 26.8135 15.5149V1.84431C25.3695 2.76579 23.6864 3.2634 21.9505 3.2634ZM19.6628 11.8374L14.0992 17.3968C13.9686 17.526 13.792 17.5997 13.6086 17.5997C13.4251 17.5997 13.2472 17.526 13.1166 17.3968L10.341 14.6171C10.07 14.3447 10.07 13.9054 10.341 13.633C10.612 13.3634 11.0526 13.362 11.325 13.633L13.6099 15.9208L18.6815 10.8534C18.9525 10.5823 19.3931 10.5823 19.6641 10.8534C19.9352 11.1244 19.9352 11.5664 19.6628 11.8374Z" fill="#4F4F4F"/>
        </svg>;

        const emailImg = <svg className="function__function-img" width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 30 30" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <g clipPath="url(#clip0)">
                <path d="M23.1254 9.375H1.87541C1.62539 9.375 1.38791 9.42627 1.17041 9.51498L11.5066 17.8437C12.0916 18.2325 12.9079 18.2312 13.5417 17.8112L23.8317 9.51498C23.6129 9.42627 23.3754 9.375 23.1254 9.375Z" fill="#4F4F4F"/>
                <path d="M24.7677 10.365L15.2114 18.0663L24.7414 24.6838C24.9014 24.4075 25.0002 24.0913 25.0002 23.75V11.25C25.0002 10.9275 24.9114 10.63 24.7677 10.365Z" fill="#4F4F4F"/>
                <path d="M14.1738 18.8688C13.6438 19.1963 13.0638 19.3725 12.4838 19.3725C11.9 19.3725 11.325 19.2012 10.8175 18.875L1.25879 25.5125C1.45256 25.58 1.65752 25.625 1.87502 25.625H23.125C23.3425 25.625 23.5476 25.58 23.7413 25.5125L14.1738 18.8688Z" fill="#4F4F4F"/>
                <path d="M0.2325 10.365C0.0887695 10.63 0 10.9287 0 11.25V23.75C0 24.0912 0.0987305 24.4075 0.25875 24.6837L9.79125 18.065L0.2325 10.365Z" fill="#4F4F4F"/>
                <path d="M28.125 4.37503H6.875C5.84123 4.37503 5 5.21626 5 6.25003V8.12503H23.75C25.1312 8.12503 26.25 9.24376 26.25 10.6251V20.625H28.125C29.1588 20.625 30 19.7838 30 18.75V6.25003C30 5.21626 29.1588 4.37503 28.125 4.37503Z" fill="#4F4F4F"/>
            </g>
            <defs>
                <clipPath id="clip0">
                    <rect width="30" height="30" fill="white"/>
                </clipPath>
            </defs>
        </svg>;

        const dinamicCoversImg = <svg className="function__function-img" width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 30 30" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M18.1025 11.53L16.6975 12.9363L18.605 15.225C18.8263 15.49 18.79 15.885 18.5263 16.1063C18.4088 16.2025 18.2663 16.25 18.125 16.25C17.9462 16.25 17.7688 16.1738 17.645 16.025L11.875 9.10126L6.25 15.8513V18.75H23.75V17.7413L18.1025 11.53Z" fill="#4F4F4F"/>
            <path d="M25.625 0H4.37504C2.6525 0 1.25 1.4025 1.25 3.12498V26.875C1.25 28.5987 2.6525 29.9999 4.37498 29.9999H25.625C27.3488 29.9999 28.75 28.5987 28.75 26.875V3.12498C28.75 1.4025 27.3488 0 25.625 0ZM25 19.375C25 19.72 24.72 20 24.375 20H5.62502C5.28002 20 5 19.72 5 19.375V4.37502C5 4.03002 5.28002 3.75 5.62502 3.75H24.375C24.72 3.75 25 4.03002 25 4.37502V19.375Z" fill="#4F4F4F"/>
        </svg>;

        const allAnalyticsImg = <svg className="function__function-img" width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 30 30" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <g clipPath="url(#clip0)">
                <path d="M6.25006 18.75H1.25002C0.90502 18.75 0.625 19.03 0.625 19.375V29.375C0.625 29.72 0.90502 30.0001 1.25002 30.0001H6.25C6.595 30.0001 6.87502 29.72 6.87502 29.375V19.375C6.87502 19.03 6.59506 18.75 6.25006 18.75Z" fill="#4F4F4F"/>
                <path d="M13.75 12.5H8.75002C8.40502 12.5 8.125 12.78 8.125 13.125V29.375C8.125 29.72 8.40502 30 8.75002 30H13.75C14.095 30 14.375 29.72 14.375 29.375V13.125C14.375 12.78 14.095 12.5 13.75 12.5Z" fill="#4F4F4F"/>
                <path d="M21.25 6.25003H16.25C15.905 6.25003 15.625 6.53005 15.625 6.87505V29.3751C15.625 29.7201 15.905 30.0001 16.25 30.0001H21.25C21.595 30.0001 21.875 29.7201 21.875 29.3751V6.87505C21.875 6.52999 21.595 6.25003 21.25 6.25003Z" fill="#4F4F4F"/>
                <path d="M28.75 0H23.75C23.405 0 23.125 0.28002 23.125 0.62502V29.375C23.125 29.72 23.405 30.0001 23.75 30.0001H28.75C29.095 30.0001 29.375 29.72 29.375 29.375V0.62502C29.375 0.28002 29.095 0 28.75 0Z" fill="#4F4F4F"/>
            </g>
            <defs>
                <clipPath id="clip0">
                    <rect width="30" height="30" fill="white"/>
                </clipPath>
            </defs>
        </svg>;

        return(
            <section className="functions-block container">
                <div className="functions__decorate-element">
                    <Function side="left" top="15%" img={constructorImg} headline="Заголовок" description="Тут должен быть текст"/>
                    <Function side="right" top="15%" img={userMonitoringImg} headline="Заголовок" description="Тут должен быть текст"/>
                    <Function side="left" top="30%" img={starImg} headline="Заголовок" description="Тут должен быть текст"/>
                    <Function side="right" top="30%" img={autoPostingImg} headline="Заголовок" description="Тут должен быть текст"/>
                    <Function side="left" top="45%" img={refreshImg} headline="Заголовок" description="Тут должен быть текст"/>
                    <Function side="right" top="45%" img={communituFillingImg} headline="Заголовок" description="Тут должен быть текст"/>
                    <Function side="left" top="60%" img={botsCleaningImg} headline="Заголовок" description="Тут должен быть текст"/>
                    <Function side="right" top="60%" img={emailImg} headline="Заголовок" description="Тут должен быть текст"/>
                    <Function side="left" top="75%" img={dinamicCoversImg} headline="Заголовок" description="Тут должен быть текст"/>
                    <Function side="right" top="75%" img={allAnalyticsImg} headline="Заголовок" description="Тут должен быть текст"/>
                </div>
            </section>
        )
    }
}
```

CSS код к нему:

```
.functions-block{
    height:741px;
    padding-top:21px;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    z-index: 2;
}

.functions__decorate-element{
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    width:19.631578947368%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:url("./img/decorate-phone.svg")no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
}
```

2) Блок непосредственно элемента в котором располагаются SVG-картинки:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './function.css'

export default class Function extends Component{

    render(){

        const leftFunctionBlock = {
            right:"56.6%",
            top:this.props.top
        };

        const leftTailStyle = {
            border : "20px solid transparent",
            borderRight : "20px solid #FFFFFF",
            float:"right",
            marginTop:"35px",
            marginLeft:"-30px"
        };

        const rightFunctionBlock = {
            left:"56.9%",
            top:this.props.top,
            paddingLeft:"20px"
        };

        const rightTailStyle = {
            border: "20px solid transparent",
            borderLeft: "20px solid #FFFFFF",
            float:"left",
            marginTop:"35px",
            marginLeft:"-20px"
        };

        if(this.props.side=="left"){
            return(
                <div style={leftFunctionBlock} className="functions__webots-function">
                    <aside style={leftTailStyle} className="block-tail"></aside>
                    <div className="function__content">
                        {this.props.img}
                        <div>
                            <p className="function__headline">{this.props.headline}</p>
                            <p className="function__description">{this.props.description}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }else if(this.props.side=="right"){
            return(
                <div style={rightFunctionBlock} className="functions__webots-function">
                    <aside style={rightTailStyle} className="block-tail"></aside>
                    <div className="function__content">
                        {this.props.img}
                        <div>
                            <p className="function__headline">{this.props.headline}</p>
                            <p className="function__description">{this.props.description}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Стили к нему:

```
.functions__function{
    height:60px;
    width:18.229166666666%;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-left:30px;
    position:absolute;
}

.block-tail{
    height:0;
    width:0;
}

.function__content{
    height:60px;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    align-items:center;
    font-family: Gotham Pro;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.function__function-img{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    margin-right:20px;
}

.function__headline{
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 13px;
    color: #5EC8D9;
    margin-bottom:7px;
}

.function__description{
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 11px;
    color: #22252A;
}
```

Если убрать скрытую SVG из шапки то результат будет выглядеть так:

[image: Так выглядит странный результат который я получаю]

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/dyoYJrG - у меня вот так это получилось

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/ExjVQga  и вот так

Comment: @MaximLensky А откуда код берешь? Автор в вопросе привел только код иконки

Comment: @MaximLensky быстро однако рисуешь. Нужно авторский код запросить, оттуда проблемы идут. Моё предположение, - что иконки имеют разные размер и более большие подрезаются родительским контейнером

Comment: @MaximLensky, я добавил код 2х компонентов, посмотри пожалуйста, мне кажется дело не в родителе. В принципе сейчас всё корректно отображается, но меня напрягает этот костыль) И я не пойму почему так случилось вообще, никогда с таким не встречался

Comment: @MaximLensky, добавил картинку, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: ищите незакрытые теги или другие ошибки синтаксиса https://validator.nu/

Comment: второе что я увидел - повторяющиеся идентификаторы

Answer (score 3):

Если в вашем приложении позиционирование и масштабирование родительских контейнеров для всех иконок одинаковые, а выглядят они по разному, то логично предположить, что причина этого находится в самих иконках.

Попробуйте сравнить проблемные иконки и нормальные по внутреннему содержанию, как они внутри наполняют холст SVG.

Вот проблемная иконка (которая отображается у вас меньшим размером):

Чтобы увидеть границы холста SVG добавьте в код иконки `border`

```
style="border:1px solid red"
```

```html
<svg width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 30 30" fill="none" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="border:1px solid red;">
        <g clip-path="url(#clip0)" >
        <path d="M26.8762 11.8749C25.3661 11.8749 24.1048 12.95 23.8148 14.375H22.2635L19.7222 9.29361C18.9771 7.80106 17.4758 6.87478 15.8083 6.87478H15.0008V4.99973C15.0008 4.65472 14.7207 4.37469 14.3757 4.37469H9.37559C9.03057 4.37469 8.75055 4.65472 8.75055 4.99973V9.99986C8.75055 10.3449 9.03057 10.6249 9.37559 10.6249H14.3757C14.7207 10.6249 15.0008 10.3449 15.0008 9.99986V8.1248H15.8083C17.0008 8.1248 18.0721 8.78606 18.6033 9.85238L20.8647 14.375H2.13411L4.81667 11.6925C5.06043 11.4487 5.06043 11.0524 4.81667 10.8087C4.57292 10.5649 4.17663 10.5649 3.93288 10.8087L0.184049 14.5575C0.126566 14.615 0.0802759 14.685 0.047814 14.7612C-0.015938 14.9137 -0.015938 15.0863 0.047814 15.2387C0.0790454 15.3162 0.125336 15.385 0.184049 15.4425L3.93294 19.1913C4.05546 19.3139 4.21542 19.3751 4.37545 19.3751C4.53547 19.3751 4.69544 19.3139 4.81796 19.1926C5.06172 18.9488 5.06172 18.5525 4.81796 18.3088L2.13411 15.6249H22.1147L19.8534 20.1476C19.3209 21.2138 18.2509 21.8751 17.0583 21.8751H16.1883C15.8983 20.4501 14.6358 19.375 13.127 19.375C11.4019 19.375 10.0006 20.7764 10.0006 22.5001C10.0006 24.2239 11.4019 25.6252 13.1257 25.6252C14.6358 25.6252 15.897 24.5501 16.187 23.1251H17.0571C18.7259 23.1251 20.2259 22.1988 20.9709 20.7063L23.5123 15.6249H23.8135C24.1035 17.0499 25.3661 18.125 26.8749 18.125C28.5987 18.125 29.9999 16.7236 29.9999 14.9999C30 13.2762 28.6 11.8749 26.8762 11.8749Z" fill="#4F4F4F"/>
        </g>
        <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip0">
        <rect width="30" height="30" fill="white"/>
        </clipPath>
        </defs>
    </svg>
```

Сразу стало видно, что иконка нарисована правильно, - заполняет весь холст SVG и её легко можно позиционировать и масштабировать.

Попробуйте для начала простой способ,- увеличьте размер иконки, изменяя `width="60"` `height="60"` внутри иконки

```html
<svg width="60" height="60" viewBox="0 0 30 30" fill="none" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="border:1px solid red;">
        <g clip-path="url(#clip0)" >
        <path d="M26.8762 11.8749C25.3661 11.8749 24.1048 12.95 23.8148 14.375H22.2635L19.7222 9.29361C18.9771 7.80106 17.4758 6.87478 15.8083 6.87478H15.0008V4.99973C15.0008 4.65472 14.7207 4.37469 14.3757 4.37469H9.37559C9.03057 4.37469 8.75055 4.65472 8.75055 4.99973V9.99986C8.75055 10.3449 9.03057 10.6249 9.37559 10.6249H14.3757C14.7207 10.6249 15.0008 10.3449 15.0008 9.99986V8.1248H15.8083C17.0008 8.1248 18.0721 8.78606 18.6033 9.85238L20.8647 14.375H2.13411L4.81667 11.6925C5.06043 11.4487 5.06043 11.0524 4.81667 10.8087C4.57292 10.5649 4.17663 10.5649 3.93288 10.8087L0.184049 14.5575C0.126566 14.615 0.0802759 14.685 0.047814 14.7612C-0.015938 14.9137 -0.015938 15.0863 0.047814 15.2387C0.0790454 15.3162 0.125336 15.385 0.184049 15.4425L3.93294 19.1913C4.05546 19.3139 4.21542 19.3751 4.37545 19.3751C4.53547 19.3751 4.69544 19.3139 4.81796 19.1926C5.06172 18.9488 5.06172 18.5525 4.81796 18.3088L2.13411 15.6249H22.1147L19.8534 20.1476C19.3209 21.2138 18.2509 21.8751 17.0583 21.8751H16.1883C15.8983 20.4501 14.6358 19.375 13.127 19.375C11.4019 19.375 10.0006 20.7764 10.0006 22.5001C10.0006 24.2239 11.4019 25.6252 13.1257 25.6252C14.6358 25.6252 15.897 24.5501 16.187 23.1251H17.0571C18.7259 23.1251 20.2259 22.1988 20.9709 20.7063L23.5123 15.6249H23.8135C24.1035 17.0499 25.3661 18.125 26.8749 18.125C28.5987 18.125 29.9999 16.7236 29.9999 14.9999C30 13.2762 28.6 11.8749 26.8762 11.8749Z" fill="#4F4F4F"/>
        </g>
        <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip0">
        <rect width="30" height="30" fill="white"/>
        </clipPath>
        </defs>
    </svg>
```

*Добавьте иконку в ваше приложение, если результат вас устроит, то можно остановиться в поисках причины.*

Если нет, то продолжайте сравнивать, чем же всё таки отличаются иконки друг от друга и устраните это различие.

Для масштабирования я уже показал, что можно использовать `width`, `height` в шапке svg файла. 
Другой прием, - изменение `viewBox`
 Основное правило здесь одно,- **при увеличении параметров `viewBox`** картинка уменьшается.

**При уменьшении viewBox**,- картинка увеличивается, но есть опасность, что она может быть подрезана по краям.
Более подробно с картинками о viewBox: [Трансформация изображений SVG при изменении параметров Viewbox](https://svg-art.ru/?p=5)

---

Чтобы избежать этих проблем, - с разным позиционированием, масштабированием старайтесь брать иконки из одного набора.

Answer (score 2):

Я исходя из тех данных что получил собрал весь SVG документ из спрайтов что облегчает работу...разбил на фрагменты

Когда собираешь в ручную весь документ важно указать правильный `viewBox` это условные px cm mm не важно как их назвать ...

**Увидел собственную ошибку - исправил**

**Из за ошибок во viewBox и могут обрезаться ваши иконки**

Выглядит это так:

```css
body {
  background: #fafafa;
}

.icon {
  fill: ;
}

.marker {
  fill: #ddd;
}

 .l1{
 
 }
 use{
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1;
 }
```

```html
<svg style="width:0;height: 0;">
  <defs>
  <g id="user">
    <path  d="M15 0C6.72915 0 0 6.72915 0 15C0 23.2708 6.72915 29.9999 15 29.9999C23.2708 29.9999 29.9999 23.2708 29.9999 15C29.9999 6.72915 23.2709 0 15 0ZM15 3.91304C17.5174 3.91304 19.5652 5.96085 19.5652 8.47828C19.5652 10.9957 17.5174 13.0435 15 13.0435C12.4825 13.0435 10.4347 10.9957 10.4347 8.47828C10.4347 5.96085 12.4826 3.91304 15 3.91304ZM22.8261 23.4782H7.17389C6.81389 23.4782 6.52169 23.1861 6.52169 22.8261C6.52169 18.1513 10.3252 14.3478 15 14.3478C19.6748 14.3478 23.4782 18.1513 23.4782 22.8261C23.4782 23.1861 23.1861 23.4782 22.8261 23.4782Z" />
  </g>

  <g id="star">
    <path d="M29.9696 11.5149C29.8822 11.2449 29.6318 11.061 29.3474 11.061H18.7394L15.6221 1.08424C15.4512 0.541628 14.5473 0.541628 14.3765 1.08424L11.2592 11.061H0.65253C0.368169 11.061 0.117741 11.2449 0.0303719 11.5149C-0.054429 11.7849 0.0421107 12.0796 0.272974 12.2453L8.99621 18.4747L5.25935 28.441C5.1589 28.7097 5.24498 29.0123 5.47193 29.1871C5.70017 29.3632 6.01192 29.3658 6.24933 29.2014L15 22.9498L23.7506 29.2014C23.8653 29.2823 23.9971 29.3227 24.1301 29.3227C24.2697 29.3227 24.4106 29.2784 24.528 29.1871C24.7549 29.0123 24.841 28.7097 24.7406 28.441L21.0037 18.4747L29.7269 12.2453C29.9579 12.0796 30.0544 11.7849 29.9696 11.5149Z"/>          
  </g>

  <g id="time">
    <path d="M14.9998 15.6536C15.3608 15.6536 15.6534 15.361 15.6534 15C15.6534 14.639 15.3608 14.3464 14.9998 14.3464C14.6388 14.3464 14.3462 14.639 14.3462 15C14.3462 15.361 14.6388 15.6536 14.9998 15.6536Z" />
    <path d="M28.0118 15C28.0118 14.6392 28.3046 14.3464 28.6654 14.3464H30C29.664 6.56734 23.4314 0.33462 15.6536 0V1.33333C15.6536 1.69412 15.3608 1.98695 15 1.98695C14.6392 1.98695 14.3464 1.69412 14.3464 1.33333V0C6.56734 0.33462 0.33462 6.56734 0 14.3464H1.33462C1.6954 14.3464 1.98824 14.6392 1.98824 15C1.98824 15.3608 1.6954 15.6536 1.33462 15.6536H0C0.33462 23.4314 6.56734 29.664 14.3464 30V28.6667C14.3464 28.3059 14.6392 28.0131 15 28.0131C15.3608 28.0131 15.6536 28.3059 15.6536 28.6667V30C23.4314 29.6654 29.664 23.4327 30 15.6536H28.6654C28.3046 15.6536 28.0118 15.3608 28.0118 15ZM20.6902 20.6902C20.5621 20.8183 20.3948 20.8811 20.2275 20.8811C20.0601 20.8811 19.8928 20.817 19.7647 20.6902L15.8431 16.7686C15.8419 16.7673 15.8405 16.7647 15.8392 16.7634C15.583 16.8863 15.3007 16.9608 14.9974 16.9608C13.9163 16.9608 13.0366 16.0811 13.0366 15C13.0366 14.149 13.5843 13.4301 14.3438 13.1595V5.84969C14.3438 5.48891 14.6366 5.19608 14.9974 5.19608C15.3581 5.19608 15.651 5.48891 15.651 5.84969V13.1595C16.4105 13.4301 16.9581 14.149 16.9581 15C16.9581 15.302 16.8836 15.5856 16.7608 15.8419C16.7621 15.8431 16.7647 15.8445 16.766 15.8458L20.6876 19.7673C20.9464 20.0222 20.9464 20.4353 20.6902 20.6902Z"/>           
  </g>
  <g id="autopost">
    <path d="M15.6027 3.01332C15.5701 2.93243 15.5218 2.86071 15.4605 2.80073L12.8531 0.190759C12.5988 -0.0635863 12.1853 -0.0635863 11.9309 0.190759C11.6766 0.445104 11.6766 0.858598 11.9309 1.11294L13.5235 2.70553C7.38538 3.43983 2.60889 8.66895 2.60889 15.0002C2.60889 20.8358 6.5845 25.8027 12.2766 27.0822C12.3249 27.0927 12.3718 27.0979 12.4188 27.0979C12.7175 27.0979 12.9874 26.8918 13.0553 26.5879C13.1349 26.2358 12.9132 25.8875 12.5623 25.808C7.47018 24.6654 3.91326 20.2202 3.91326 15.0002C3.91326 9.47509 7.9815 4.89296 13.2784 4.06078L11.9297 5.40813C11.6753 5.66248 11.6753 6.07597 11.9297 6.33032C12.0575 6.45816 12.2244 6.52206 12.3914 6.52206C12.5584 6.52206 12.7253 6.45816 12.8531 6.3316L15.4605 3.72426C15.5204 3.66428 15.5687 3.59122 15.6026 3.51167C15.6692 3.35246 15.6692 3.17247 15.6027 3.01332Z" />
    <path d="M27.3913 15.0002C27.3913 9.16463 23.4157 4.19768 17.7236 2.91813C17.3675 2.8425 17.0232 3.06029 16.9436 3.41246C16.8641 3.76463 17.0858 4.11288 17.4379 4.19243C22.53 5.33502 26.087 9.78019 26.087 15.0001C26.087 20.5253 22.0187 25.1074 16.7219 25.9396L18.0692 24.5922C18.3236 24.3379 18.3236 23.9244 18.0692 23.6701C17.8149 23.4157 17.4014 23.4157 17.147 23.6701L14.5397 26.2774C14.4797 26.3374 14.4314 26.4104 14.3975 26.49C14.331 26.6491 14.331 26.8291 14.3975 26.9882C14.4301 27.0691 14.4784 27.1408 14.5397 27.2008L17.147 29.8082C17.2749 29.936 17.4418 29.9999 17.6088 29.9999C17.7758 29.9999 17.9427 29.936 18.0705 29.8094C18.3249 29.5551 18.3249 29.1416 18.0705 28.8873L16.4779 27.2947C22.6149 26.5605 27.3913 21.3314 27.3913 15.0002Z" />  
  </g>
  <g id="post">
    <path d="M29.375 5.625H9.37502C9.03002 5.625 8.75 5.90502 8.75 6.25002C8.75 6.59502 9.03002 6.87504 9.37502 6.87504H29.375C29.72 6.87504 30 6.59502 30 6.25002C30 5.90502 29.72 5.625 29.375 5.625Z" />
    <path d="M29.375 14.375H9.37502C9.03002 14.375 8.75 14.655 8.75 15C8.75 15.345 9.03002 15.625 9.37502 15.625H29.375C29.72 15.625 30 15.345 30 15C30 14.655 29.72 14.375 29.375 14.375Z" />
    <path d="M29.375 23.125H9.37502C9.03002 23.125 8.75 23.405 8.75 23.75C8.75 24.095 9.03002 24.3751 9.37502 24.3751H29.375C29.72 24.3751 30 24.095 30 23.75C30 23.405 29.72 23.125 29.375 23.125Z" />
    <path d="M3.12498 26.875C4.85086 26.875 6.24996 25.4759 6.24996 23.75C6.24996 22.0241 4.85086 20.625 3.12498 20.625C1.3991 20.625 0 22.0241 0 23.75C0 25.4759 1.3991 26.875 3.12498 26.875Z" />
    <path d="M3.12498 18.125C4.85086 18.125 6.24996 16.7259 6.24996 15C6.24996 13.2741 4.85086 11.875 3.12498 11.875C1.3991 11.875 0 13.2741 0 15C0 16.7259 1.3991 18.125 3.12498 18.125Z" />
    <path d="M3.12498 9.37501C4.85086 9.37501 6.24996 7.97591 6.24996 6.25003C6.24996 4.52415 4.85086 3.12505 3.12498 3.12505C1.3991 3.12505 0 4.52415 0 6.25003C0 7.97591 1.3991 9.37501 3.12498 9.37501Z" />   
  </g>
  <g id="shit">
    <path d="M21.9505 3.2634C19.2416 3.2634 16.708 2.05976 14.9998 0C13.2931 2.0584 10.7594 3.2634 8.05055 3.2634C6.31321 3.2634 4.63014 2.76585 3.18604 1.84295V15.5149C3.18604 22.6337 13.0373 28.8353 14.9998 30C16.9608 28.8353 26.8135 22.6268 26.8135 15.5149V1.84431C25.3695 2.76579 23.6864 3.2634 21.9505 3.2634ZM19.6628 11.8374L14.0992 17.3968C13.9686 17.526 13.792 17.5997 13.6086 17.5997C13.4251 17.5997 13.2472 17.526 13.1166 17.3968L10.341 14.6171C10.07 14.3447 10.07 13.9054 10.341 13.633C10.612 13.3634 11.0526 13.362 11.325 13.633L13.6099 15.9208L18.6815 10.8534C18.9525 10.5823 19.3931 10.5823 19.6641 10.8534C19.9352 11.1244 19.9352 11.5664 19.6628 11.8374Z" />
  </g>  
  <g id="mail">
    <path d="M23.1254 9.375H1.87541C1.62539 9.375 1.38791 9.42627 1.17041 9.51498L11.5066 17.8437C12.0916 18.2325 12.9079 18.2312 13.5417 17.8112L23.8317 9.51498C23.6129 9.42627 23.3754 9.375 23.1254 9.375Z"/>
    <path d="M24.7677 10.365L15.2114 18.0663L24.7414 24.6838C24.9014 24.4075 25.0002 24.0913 25.0002 23.75V11.25C25.0002 10.9275 24.9114 10.63 24.7677 10.365Z" />
    <path d="M14.1738 18.8688C13.6438 19.1963 13.0638 19.3725 12.4838 19.3725C11.9 19.3725 11.325 19.2012 10.8175 18.875L1.25879 25.5125C1.45256 25.58 1.65752 25.625 1.87502 25.625H23.125C23.3425 25.625 23.5476 25.58 23.7413 25.5125L14.1738 18.8688Z" />
    <path d="M0.2325 10.365C0.0887695 10.63 0 10.9287 0 11.25V23.75C0 24.0912 0.0987305 24.4075 0.25875 24.6837L9.79125 18.065L0.2325 10.365Z" />
    <path d="M28.125 4.37503H6.875C5.84123 4.37503 5 5.21626 5 6.25003V8.12503H23.75C25.1312 8.12503 26.25 9.24376 26.25 10.6251V20.625H28.125C29.1588 20.625 30 19.7838 30 18.75V6.25003C30 5.21626 29.1588 4.37503 28.125 4.37503Z" />
  </g>

  <g id="img">
    <path d="M18.1025 11.53L16.6975 12.9363L18.605 15.225C18.8263 15.49 18.79 15.885 18.5263 16.1063C18.4088 16.2025 18.2663 16.25 18.125 16.25C17.9462 16.25 17.7688 16.1738 17.645 16.025L11.875 9.10126L6.25 15.8513V18.75H23.75V17.7413L18.1025 11.53Z"/>
    <path d="M25.625 0H4.37504C2.6525 0 1.25 1.4025 1.25 3.12498V26.875C1.25 28.5987 2.6525 29.9999 4.37498 29.9999H25.625C27.3488 29.9999 28.75 28.5987 28.75 26.875V3.12498C28.75 1.4025 27.3488 0 25.625 0ZM25 19.375C25 19.72 24.72 20 24.375 20H5.62502C5.28002 20 5 19.72 5 19.375V4.37502C5 4.03002 5.28002 3.75 5.62502 3.75H24.375C24.72 3.75 25 4.03002 25 4.37502V19.375Z" />
  </g>
  <g id="wifi">
    <path d="M6.25006 18.75H1.25002C0.90502 18.75 0.625 19.03 0.625 19.375V29.375C0.625 29.72 0.90502 30.0001 1.25002 30.0001H6.25C6.595 30.0001 6.87502 29.72 6.87502 29.375V19.375C6.87502 19.03 6.59506 18.75 6.25006 18.75Z"/>
    <path d="M13.75 12.5H8.75002C8.40502 12.5 8.125 12.78 8.125 13.125V29.375C8.125 29.72 8.40502 30 8.75002 30H13.75C14.095 30 14.375 29.72 14.375 29.375V13.125C14.375 12.78 14.095 12.5 13.75 12.5Z" />
    <path d="M21.25 6.25003H16.25C15.905 6.25003 15.625 6.53005 15.625 6.87505V29.3751C15.625 29.7201 15.905 30.0001 16.25 30.0001H21.25C21.595 30.0001 21.875 29.7201 21.875 29.3751V6.87505C21.875 6.52999 21.595 6.25003 21.25 6.25003Z"/>
    <path d="M28.75 0H23.75C23.405 0 23.125 0.28002 23.125 0.62502V29.375C23.125 29.72 23.405 30.0001 23.75 30.0001H28.75C29.095 30.0001 29.375 29.72 29.375 29.375V0.62502C29.375 0.28002 29.095 0 28.75 0Z" /> 
  </g>
  <g id="connect">
    <path d="M26.8762 11.8749C25.3661 11.8749 24.1048 12.95 23.8148 14.375H22.2635L19.7222 9.29361C18.9771 7.80106 17.4758 6.87478 15.8083 6.87478H15.0008V4.99973C15.0008 4.65472 14.7207 4.37469 14.3757 4.37469H9.37559C9.03057 4.37469 8.75055 4.65472 8.75055 4.99973V9.99986C8.75055 10.3449 9.03057 10.6249 9.37559 10.6249H14.3757C14.7207 10.6249 15.0008 10.3449 15.0008 9.99986V8.1248H15.8083C17.0008 8.1248 18.0721 8.78606 18.6033 9.85238L20.8647 14.375H2.13411L4.81667 11.6925C5.06043 11.4487 5.06043 11.0524 4.81667 10.8087C4.57292 10.5649 4.17663 10.5649 3.93288 10.8087L0.184049 14.5575C0.126566 14.615 0.0802759 14.685 0.047814 14.7612C-0.015938 14.9137 -0.015938 15.0863 0.047814 15.2387C0.0790454 15.3162 0.125336 15.385 0.184049 15.4425L3.93294 19.1913C4.05546 19.3139 4.21542 19.3751 4.37545 19.3751C4.53547 19.3751 4.69544 19.3139 4.81796 19.1926C5.06172 18.9488 5.06172 18.5525 4.81796 18.3088L2.13411 15.6249H22.1147L19.8534 20.1476C19.3209 21.2138 18.2509 21.8751 17.0583 21.8751H16.1883C15.8983 20.4501 14.6358 19.375 13.127 19.375C11.4019 19.375 10.0006 20.7764 10.0006 22.5001C10.0006 24.2239 11.4019 25.6252 13.1257 25.6252C14.6358 25.6252 15.897 24.5501 16.187 23.1251H17.0571C18.7259 23.1251 20.2259 22.1988 20.9709 20.7063L23.5123 15.6249H23.8135C24.1035 17.0499 25.3661 18.125 26.8749 18.125C28.5987 18.125 29.9999 16.7236 29.9999 14.9999C30 13.2762 28.6 11.8749 26.8762 11.8749Z" /> 
  </g>
  <g id="phone">
  <path d="m7.2940513-94.282467c-4.0409635 0-7.2940489 3.085684-7.2940489 6.918651v377.44483c0 3.83294 3.2530854 6.919 7.2940489 6.919h184.26039c4.04095 0 7.29406-3.08606 7.29406-6.919v-377.44483c0-3.832967-3.25311-6.918651-7.29406-6.918651zm91.337124 3.723013a5.8352937 5.534971 0 0 1 5.835325 5.534986 5.8352937 5.534971 0 0 1-5.835325 5.53499 5.8352937 5.534971 0 0 1-5.835311-5.53499 5.8352937 5.534971 0 0 1 5.835311-5.534986zm-83.445636 9.128564h74.491198l9.357758 13.313869 8.577525-13.313869h74.49157c3.66061 0 6.60765 2.713255 6.60765 6.083806v331.90959c0 3.37055-2.94704 6.0838-6.60765 6.0838h-166.91805c-3.660618 0-6.6076519-2.71325-6.6076519-6.0838v-331.90959c0-3.370551 2.9470339-6.083806 6.6076519-6.083806zm58.407048 356.21085h49.355363c4.04094 0 7.29405 1.48467 7.29405 3.32866 0 1.84398-3.25311 3.32863-7.29405 3.32863h-49.355363c-4.040943 0-7.294049-1.48465-7.294049-3.32863 0-1.84399 3.253106-3.32866 7.294049-3.32866z" fill="#666" />
    </g>
    <g id="marker">
      <path d="M0,25 340,25 340,90 320,70 00,70" />
    </g>
    <g id="marker2">
       <path d="M800,15 460,15 460,70 475,55 800,55z" /> 
    </g>
  </defs>       
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 -100 500 800">
<g>
  <use xlink:href="#phone" x="150"/>
</g>

<g transform="translate(0, -440)">
 <svg width="200" viewBox="0 0 340 100" class="l1">
   <use xlink:href="#marker" x="0"/>
 </svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0  40 40" width="30">
    <use xlink:href="#wifi" x="10" y="4" fill="#fff"/> 
 </svg>
</g>
<g transform="translate(0, -380)">
  <svg width="200" viewBox="0 0 340 100" class="l1">
   <use xlink:href="#marker" x="0"/>
 </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0  40 40" width="30">
    <use xlink:href="#connect" x="10" y="4" fill="#fff"/> 
 </svg>
</g>

<g transform="translate(0, -320)">
  <svg width="200" viewBox="0 0 340 100" class="l1">
   <use xlink:href="#marker" x="0"/>
 </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0  40 40" width="30">
    <use xlink:href="#mail" x="10" y="4" fill="#fff"/> 
 </svg>
</g>

<g transform="translate(0, -260)">
  <svg width="200" viewBox="0 0 340 100" class="l1">
   <use xlink:href="#marker" x="0"/>
 </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0  40 40" width="30">
    <use xlink:href="#img" x="10" y="4" fill="#fff"/> 
 </svg>
</g>

<g transform="translate(0, -200)">
  <svg width="200" viewBox="0 0 340 100" class="l1">
   <use xlink:href="#marker" x="0"/>
 </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0  40 40" width="30">
    <use xlink:href="#shit" x="10" y="4" fill="#fff"/> 
 </svg>
</g>

<!--level 2-->

<g transform="translate(280, -480)">
  <svg width="200" viewBox="450 -100 300 140" class="l1">
   <use xlink:href="#marker2" x="0" y="-10"/>
 </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0  40 40" width="30">
    <use xlink:href="#post" x="20" y="55" fill="#fff"/> 
 </svg>
</g>

<g transform="translate(280, -420)">
  <svg width="200" viewBox="450 -100 300 140" class="l1">
   <use xlink:href="#marker2" x="0" y="-10"/>
 </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0  50 50" width="30">
    <use xlink:href="#autopost" x="20" y="70" fill="#fff"/> 
 </svg>
</g>

<g transform="translate(280, -360)">
  <svg width="200" viewBox="450 -100 300 140" class="l1">
   <use xlink:href="#marker2" x="0" y="-10"/>
 </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0  50 50" width="30">
    <use xlink:href="#time" x="20" y="70"/> 
 </svg>
</g>

<g transform="translate(280, -300)">
  <svg width="200" viewBox="450 -100 300 140" class="l1">
   <use xlink:href="#marker2" x="0" y="-10"/>
 </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0  50 50" width="30">
    <use xlink:href="#star" x="20" y="70" fill="#fff"/> 
 </svg>
</g>

<g transform="translate(280, -240)">
  <svg width="200" viewBox="450 -100 300 140" class="l1">
   <use xlink:href="#marker2" x="0" y="-10"/>
 </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0  50 50" width="30">
    <use xlink:href="#user" x="20" y="70" fill="#fff"/> 
 </svg>
</g>


</svg>
```

Comment: Да, скорее всего из-за viewBox, такая картина происходит. У иконок, которые масштабируются по разному, могут даже быть одинаковые viewBox, а выглядеть они могут по разному. Какие-то больше, какие-то меньше по размерам. Сильно зависит, как они нарисованы, на какой масштаб были изначально рассчитаны.

Comment: пишу сейчас ответ, с общими рекомендациями и кое-какими приемами по выявлению и лечению проблемы.

Comment: Загадкой остается, почему если добавить svg картинку в шапку сайта, всё начинает отображаться нормально, без изменения viewBox)

Comment: @Сергей Как правило, svg изображение масштабируется несколько раз и когда ещё добавляются масштабирование CSS, JS то последствия становятся непредсказуемыми